# std::vector to hold much more than 2^32 elements

Tags: c++, vector, containers

`std::vector::size` returns a `size_t` so I guess it can hold up to 2^32 elements.

Is there a standard container than can hold **much** more elements, e.g. 2^64 **OR** a way to tweak `std::vector` to be "indexed" by e.g. a  `unsigned long long`?

Comment: `size_t` doesn't have a defined size of 32 bits.

Comment: The only container where this is important is `std::vector<bool>`. `std::size_t` otherwise is always large enough (that's how it's defined).

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work.

Comment: Here's what the standard has on `size_t`: *The type size_t is an implementation-deﬁned unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size
in bytes of any object.*

Comment: I'm curious to know what kind of hardware you intend to use, to store 2^64 elements.

Comment: I [googled](https://www.google.ca/search?q=2^64&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=zQN&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=2^64+bytes&oq=2^64+&gs_l=serp.1.2.0l4.2908.2908.0.6658.1.1.0.0.0.0.76.76.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.6.psy-ab.97u5bNFwDoA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.aWc&fp=3f1e61731c568cda&biw=1920&bih=885) it, I don't think you have the memory for it.

Answer (score 9):

Sure. Compile a 64-bit program. `size_t` will be 64 bits wide then.

But really, what you *should* be doing is take a step back, and consider why you need such a big vector. Because most likely, you don't, and there's a better way to solve whatever problem you're working on.

Answer (score 7):

`size_t` doesn't have a predefined size, although it is often capped at 2<sup>32</sup> on 32 bit computers.

Since a `std::vector` must hold contiguous memory for all elements, you *will run out of memory before exceeding the size.*

Compile your program for a 64 bit computer and you'll have more space.

Better still, reconsider if `std::vector` is appropriate.  **Why do you want to hold trillions of adjacent objects directly in memory?**

Consider a `std::map<unsigned long long, YourData>` if you only want large indexes and aren't really trying to store trillions of objects.